# CSS @media tag Not scaling background-image to correct sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML5 and the latest CSS abilities. I'm using **@media** tag in CSS to change the styling of a header image size in my website *Bible4All*, but there seems to be a problem with the scaling. Let me explain.

As the size of the browser decreases (or screensize) the correct size background image needs to be displayed (loaded) based on the CSS **@media** tag defined.

Below is the sizes that I've setup for each of the currently supported screensizes:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: url(./images/Bible4All_1920.jpg); 
        background-size: 1920px 306px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 310px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1600px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: url(./images/Bible4All_1600.jpg); 
        background-color: #990000;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 300px;
    }    
}

@media all and (max-width: 1366px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: url(./images/Bible4All_1366.jpg); 
        background-color: #990000;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 300px;
    }    
}

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: url(./images/Bible4All_1200.jpg); 
        background-color: #990000;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 300px;
    }    
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: none; 
        background-color: #ffffff;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 300px;
    }    
}

@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: none; 
        background-color: #ffffff;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: auto;
    }    
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: none; 
        background-color: #ffffff;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: auto;
    }    
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: none; 
        background-color: #ffffff;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: auto;
    }    
}
```

**Testing process**

I don't really know how to test the **@media** tags except by scaling the browser normally and check if the picture changes.

What the image needs to look like is as follows, with the three crosses at the right and the Bible4All text on the left. See Figure 1 below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/colrx.jpg)

**Figure 1 - Image as it supposed to look like**

What seems to happen is the image is cropped at various areas and seems to not fit the entire picture correctly as according to its width. See Figure 2 below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejbEx.jpg)

**Figure 2 - Image not loading correctly**

**Added (min-width) property and only screen

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1367px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: url(./images/Bible4All_1600.jpg); 
        background-color: #990000;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 300px;
    }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1366px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: url(./images/Bible4All_1366.jpg); 
        background-color: #990000;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 300px;
    }    
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .header_top_logo{
        background-image: url(./images/Bible4All_1200.jpg); 
        background-color: #990000;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 300px;
    }    
}
```

I've added a (min-width) property to to set a range within how the @media tag responds, but no difference. I've also added the screen only attribute, without any luck.

**What is working**

During scaling, the picture of the background does seems to change to the defined image in the CSS script.

Comment: instead of using `@media all` use `@media only screen`. You want the browser's viewport width, not the device width.

Comment: As @tacoshy mentioned, switch `@media all` with `@media only screen` or simply `@media`. Also, try to add `min-width` into the mix, because as it is, you are only using `max-width` and your browser may have trouble deciding which media query to use. For example: `@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1199px)`, and then `@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1365px)`. Finally, I would have another look at the bootstrap documentation for the recommended breakpoints for each device!

Comment: @LoizosAristeidis his conditions are correct. Let's say we have a screen with 400px width then all media queries would apply. However, the last media query (the smallest)  will override all previous media queries as they value for the properties are conflicting and within the same specificity weight the last declaration applies.

Comment: Tried the changes, without any luck. It behaves the same way.

Comment: _"What seems to happen is the image is cropped at various areas and seems to not fit the entire picture correctly as according to its width."_ - background images do not change their dimensions automatically on their own; if you want them to adapt to the actual dimensions of the image they are used on, then you need to go look into the `background-size` property.

Comment: It seems to be working after adding the background-size property. However, The left of the image still behaves the same if I shrink the browser, thus until it reaches the next @media defined screen size is crops then appears correctly. Do I now have to specify the image size for more in-between sizes?  Hope I'm explaining correctly. Where can one post the answer.